# When using Postman, my post method is ignored (making a Flask API)

Tags: python, api, flask, peewee

Whenever I do a post request to http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/fliers it ignores it. I get a 200 OK status back and the database remains unchanged. My get request to the same comes back as its supposed to, but the post request is ignored.

Weird thing is everything was working fine just a bit ago, and now it isn't. I'm thoroughly confused. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from flask import jsonify, Blueprint, abort

from flask.ext.restful import (Resource, Api, reqparse,
                               inputs, fields, marshal,
                               marshal_with, url_for)

from auth import auth
import models

flier_fields = {
    'name': fields.String
}

def flier_or_404(flier_id):
    try:
        flier = models.Flier.get(models.Flier.id==flier_id)
    except models.Flier.DoesNotExist:
        abort(404)
    else:
        return flier


class FlierList(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument(
            'name',
            required=True,
            help='No name provided',
            location=['form', 'json']
        )
        super(FlierList, self).__init__()

    def get(self):
        fliers = [marshal(flier, flier_fields) for flier in     models.Flier.select()]
        return {'fliers': fliers}

    @marshal_with(flier_fields)
    @auth.login_required
    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        flier = models.Flier.create(**args)
        return (flier, 201)

class Flier(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument(
            'name',
            required=True,
            help='No name provided',
            location=['form', 'json']
        )
        super(Flier, self).__init__()

    @marshal_with(flier_fields)
    def get(self, id):
        return flier_or_404(id)

    def put(self, id):
        return 400

    @auth.login_required
    def delete(self, id):
        query = models.Flier.delete().where(models.Flier.id==id)
        query.execute()
        return ('', 204)

fliers_api = Blueprint('resources.fliers', __name__)
api = Api(fliers_api)
api.add_resource(
    FlierList,
    '/api/v1/fliers',
    endpoint='fliers'
)
api.add_resource(
    Flier,
    '/api/v1/fliers/<int:id>',
    endpoint='flier'
)
```

Comment: I am not sure about Flask, but in some frameworks you can output anywhere some text. So you can try print("hello") in different parts of code and see where it shows up. (It is returned to the post request if it works)

Comment: I've tried a number of methods of producing a result that isn't the 200 OK to include forcing a 400 code return, and it ignores it all. It acts as if the post definition is not even there. Thank you though, that was my first thoughts actually and did try it.

Comment: if you remove your `@auth.login_required` decorator, do you then see the `post` occuring?

Comment: It does work without that, I'm so confused now. auth was working fine, but I guess I need to go take a look at its code again. Thanks.

Comment: One of those moments you feel like an idiot. I had wiped out my SQL database that held the login information so when I went to use the basic_auth, it obviously failed, it just wasn't clear. This'll teach me to use better error catching.